# Restrict WHM/cPanel Access to user folder ~

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I want to restrict access to direct folder in WHM, for example I have my website: `samplesite.com`

But at the same time if I open `server-whm.com/~samplesite`, I can see the content of my website.

I need to restrict this access to open my website only from the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place this rule as **first rule** in `samplesite/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?samplesite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

This will allow `/samplesite/` to be accessed only from `samplesite.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this functionality from WHM:

1. login as root
2. go to security center > Apache mod-userdir tweak
3. tick the enable mod_userdir protection box